# webpack can not require variable ,the request of a dependency is an expression

Tags: webpack

how to require a variable.
  i can work like this

```
var config={

    example1 : require("example1/main.js"),

    example2 : require("example2/main.js")

}
```

when I  use like

```
var modules=["example1","example2"]

_.each(modules,function(module){

    require(module+"/main.js")

})
```

this error is "Cannot find module 'example1/main.js"

Comment: can you elaborate a little?  its hard to understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar problem and solved it by specifying the full path, e.g., in your case:

```
var modules=["example1","example2"];

_.each(modules,function(module){

  require("./"+module+"/main.js");

});
```

Maybe [this example](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/require.context#examplejs) can help you.

This type of error is related to the [context](https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html).