# Is it possible to load in browser a module dynamically by name stored in a variable?

Tags: javascript, module, webpack, browserify, systemjs

I would like to be able to configure at the run time which modules to load in browser like that:

```
var moduleName  =  'my-module'
var module = require(moduleName)
```

It does't seem to work out of the box with but perhaps there is some way?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241662/using-require-with-a-variable-vs-using-a-string-in-webpack

Comment: I checked the syntax of the import keyword, the path to the module must be string literal.

Have you reach to an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There are many ways

1. Webpack Hot Module Replacement Feature

   https://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement.html

Example from Webpack Docs

```
var requestHandler = require("./handler.js");
var server = require("http").createServer();
server.on("request", requestHandler);
server.listen(8080);

// check if HMR is enabled
if(module.hot) {
    // accept update of dependency
    module.hot.accept("./handler.js", function() {
        // replace request handler of server
        server.removeListener("request", requestHandler);
        requestHandler = require("./handler.js");
        server.on("request", requestHandler);
    });
}
```

For methods check this answer

[How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Comment: Thank you, but will it only work with webpack running? Can I use it to compile production bundle that would load the module?