# Vuejs: Cannot find module "."

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, webpack-file-loader

When I pass a string to file-loader require method in computed property it works fine, like this

```
computedProp () {
  return require('../path/to/file');
}
```

but if I try to pass some variable into it it throws error

```
computedProp () {
  const l = '../path/to/file';
  return require(l);
}
```

Error: `Error: Cannot find module "."`

How can I fix that? I want to create the relative path based on some condition and then want to pass it to require method to get an absolute path.

Answer (score 3):

Very similar answers had been posted in Stack:

> Since Webpack is running in build-time, it can't figure out which
>   modules to bundle when the name is a dynamic variable. You can give it
>   hints by specifying part of the path (for example, if you know all the
>   modules are in a single directory).

[Using require('...') with a variable vs. using a string in webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241662/using-require-with-a-variable-vs-using-a-string-in-webpack/37241982)

So, for that to work you could test:

```
computedProp () {
  const path = '../path/to'
  const file = 'file';
  return require(path + '/' + file);
}
```

More info [Here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/require.context#examplejs) and [Here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html)

Hope it helps.