# Webpack dynamic require throwing error

Tags: javascript, webpack-2, commonjs

I have the following piece of code that works well:

```
require.ensure(['./core/sample-form.js'], require => {
    require('./core/sample-form.js');  
});
```

Now if I put that string into a variable:

```
const ajaxJs = './core/sample-form.js';
require.ensure([ajaxJs], require => {
    require(ajaxJs);  // eslint-disable-line import/no-dynamic-require
});
```

It throws the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module "." at webpackMissingModule

Is there any way I can use a variable for that require?

Comment: Try `ajaxJs = ['./core/sample-form.js'];` ... `require.ensure(ajaxJs, require => {`

Comment: Unfortunately it throws the same error

Comment: Seen this already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446844/dynamic-require-in-requirejs-getting-module-name-has-not-been-loaded-yet-for-c

Comment: Dynamic require is NOT es6, its CommonJS: https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#commonjs-require-ensure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at Webpack's [Context Module](https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html).

Apparently, when you attempt to dynamicly require a module, Webpack will try to parse the input expression to a `context`.

Try the following code (***haven't tested this***):

```
const ajaxJs = './sample-form.js';
core = require.context('./core', true, /^\.\/.*\.js$/);
require.ensure([], () => {
    core(ajaxJs);
});
```

Comment: @Pete Yeah, wasn't sure about that. Glad you sorted it out

Answer (score 0):

Webpack can't figure out which modules to bundle when the name is dynamic variable. You can't use variable name in `require`. You'll have to do something like :

```
require.ensure(['./core/sample-form.js'], require => {
    require('./core/sample-form.js');  // eslint-disable-line import/no-dynamic-require
});
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37241982/2648216) answer can help.

Comment: Surely you should be able to use dynamic requires otherwise there wouldn't be a warning in eslint about it?  I may be wrong, but it seems daft to only warn you about it rather than just throw an error if you can't do it?

Comment: Seems like the use of webpack's context module can do this. As @matias-cicero answered.