# Why doesn't require() function accept variables?

Tags: webpack

I have an image tag:

`<img :src="getImage(file.path)">`

that dynamically requires an image src by calling this method:

```
getImage(value) {
  return require(value)
}
```

The problem is, it only works when I specify the string directly in the `require()` function.

I tested it by using a hardcoded value rather than the input `value` just to see what's going on. Could you please explain why does this below happens?:

#### Works

```
  getImage(value) {
    return require('C:/Users/name/Desktop/1.png')
  }
```

#### Doesn't work

```
  getImage(value) {
    var image = 'C:/Users/name/Desktop/1.png'
    return require(image)
  }
```

throws this error:
`Error: Cannot find module "."`

So it doesn't allow me to use that input `value` because it only works with a string directly specified in the `required()`

---

### UPDATE

If `require()` is not the way I should be loading images in JS, please could you tell me how do I do it in JS?

**P.S.** it's an Electron project, opened on localhost with webpack's server.

Comment: No, require has nothing to do with the javascript language - read the answers in that link

Comment: This is a Webpack issue, not a pure JS issue. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241662/using-require-with-a-variable-vs-using-a-string-in-webpack/37241982) may be helpful.

Comment: @Un1: It might be part of some language that compiles to JS, or of whatever JS library you're using (though in that case it wouldn't matter whether the string was a literal or a variable), but it's not part of JS proper.

Comment: Maybe it can help you https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6391 . If you want to load image dynamically you should send http request on server and get image from server side.

Comment: Guys it's an electron app, there's no server, i'm just trying to dynamically load an image with JS, what am I doing wrong there?

Comment: No need for wrapping it with `require` call. Just return the resource's URL.

Answer (score 0):

`require` does not run on the browser.  It is compiled and therefore can't take a runtime variable.  The link in the comments explains more.

[What is this Javascript "require"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901082/what-is-this-javascript-require)

Comment: Could you please tell me then, how do I load an image in JS? Do I still use the `:src="functionName(path)"` to load an image? Or there are better ways?

Comment: Your function should just return the image source as a string and the browser will load it for the user. I think you can also load images in js with the Image class but you probably don’t need that

Comment: I realized that I'm doing it completely wrong, could you delete your answer please so I can delete the question so that it doesn't confuse people?