# webpack require, how to pass a string variable?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-component, require

In Vue, I'm trying to pass a string into require(),
the first option works (passing the string directly).
however when passing the variable containing the string the loading fails,
any clues???

```
<template>
    <img :src="require('@/assets/channels/email.png')" />
//   <img :src="require(test)" />
</template>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      test: "@/assets/channels/email.png"
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using require('...') with a variable vs. using a string in webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241662/using-require-with-a-variable-vs-using-a-string-in-webpack)

Answer (score 0):

Maximum you could is a require with expression, with full variable it wont work. See [docs here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-with-expression)

```
<template>
    <img :src="require('@/assets/channels/'+test+'.png')" />
</template>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      test: "email"
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Mmm... care to fix typo / explain why it won't work?