# require() does not accept javascript variable having string

Tags: javascript

My question is straight forward

```
var path = './App.vue'

//var App = require(path);  //THIS WILL NOT WORK
var App = require('./App.vue'); //THIS WORKS
```

DEMO HERE : 
[require() does not accept javascript variable having string](https://codesandbox.io/s/example-e-commerce-pnn1v)

If I want to make it work as to accept javascipt varibales as strings, what I should do.

Comment: Generally, you shouldn’t do that.

Comment: Why would you want to do this in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

That's a good question. I know webpack doesn't like it when you do it because I read this:

[Using require('...') with a variable vs. using a string in webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241662/using-require-with-a-variable-vs-using-a-string-in-webpack/37241982)

But I also think it's weird that this works:

```
var App = require(`${path}`);
```

I'm just curios, why do you need it to be a variable? The reason it might not work is a tool like webpack would need to know the path before it ran any code so that it can bundle all your modules.