# Why does require not work on react when it is past with a function?

Tags: reactjs, require, dynamic-import

I have the following component in react that dinamically loads an image:

```
<img src {require(getImgPath()).default}/>
```

This component throws the following error: `Cannot find module './images/abc.svg'`

If I change the component to the following:

```
<img src {require(`${getImgPath()}`).default}/>
```

Then it works. Why is that?

I also tried this without success:

```
<img src {require(getImgPath().toString()).default}/>
```

Comment: Did you try `require(() => getImgPath())`

Answer (score -1):

```
 <Image style={{width:"100%",height:75,borderTopRightRadius:6,borderTopLeftRadius:6,marginBottom:5}}
          source={{
            uri: 'https://example.com/'+param.id.toString()+'.jpg',
  }} />
```

U can use dynamic path with Image component.

Comment: This is still not answering my question :(

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/37241662/14925784 answer can help you