# Requiring array of modules in Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am currently trying to load a variable array of modules with Webpack.
I've found this link: [webpack can not require variable ,the request of a dependency is an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31694346/webpack-can-not-require-variable-the-request-of-a-dependency-is-an-expression/33048000#33048000) but it doesn't seem to work for me.

In my project I've got a module inside my *node_modules* folder. The entry point of the module is called *index.js*.

Here's the basic structure:

```
| app
+---app.js
| js
+---gen.js
| node_modules
  +---sample_module_1
  |   +---index.js
  +-sample-module_2
      +---index.js
| webpack.config.js
```

In future I'd like to add new modules. Therefore I tried following approach:

```
//app.js

var modules = [
  "sample_module_1",
  "sample_module_2"
]

for(var i = 0; i < modules.length; i++) {
  require(modules[i] + "/index.js");
}
```

But Webpack doesn't seem to find the module. I've tried adding a resolveLoader to the *webpack.config.js* file:

```
//webpack.config.js

var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './app/app.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'gen.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'js')
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    modules: ["node_modules"],
    extensions: ['*', '.js']
  }
};
```

Still, Webpack is not able to find the module.

I've also tried the suggestions on https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html but still no results.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your webpack.config.js might help in debugging. Similarly, the layout of your package, with node_modules should help.