# React: How to reference an image url in require

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a data file api that has bunch of images url stored locally

```
   const url =[
          { title:img1,
            img_src="./img/img1.png"
          },
          { title:img2,
            img_src="./img/img2.png"
          },
          { title:img3,
            img_src="./img/img3.png"
          }
      ]
```

And using react/redux I pass the url state as props to my react components.Next I want to display them in my components by using require

```
<img src=require(?)/>
```

What's the appropriate syntax here? I've used es6 template string `${this.props.urls.img_src}` but it throws an error that it couldn't resolve the path. I've tried to require("./img/img1.png") just to test to rule out broken path and it worked. But still wouldnt work if you reference it using a prop.

**Solution**

After researching, and thanks to Rei Dien for the input, I now can use variables in require by using context require

`<img src={require("./img/"+this.props.img_src)}/>`

Comment: use the new import. i believe it can take a variable, im not quite sure if require can take a variable. http://2ality.com/2017/01/import-operator.html

Comment: Hey thank you for the reply. your answer sort of guided into finding the solution. I researched on require accepting variables, and it usually does but webpack only does static string dependencies, so it can't resolve the path. All to solve it I had to do [context require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31694346/webpack-can-not-require-variable-the-request-of-a-dependency-is-an-expression/33048000#33048000).

Comment: oh i see you are using webpack then. glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

since require works in static mode during build process on node only so follow following steps.

1) take all image urls and store them in a javascript file
so

//imageURLs.js

```
import image1 from "path_to_image_file_1";
import image2 from "path_to_image_file_2";
import image3 from "path_to_image_file_3";/**do like this for all images stored locally, image1, image2,.. are the image identifiers(title in your case) you would get in api call**/
export const urls = {image1, image2, image3};
```

//image usage file

read api for identifier and

```
import imageURLs from './imageURLs.js';
<img src={imageURLs[image_id_from_api]}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you passed the url in the props, you can do this :

```
this.props.url.map(n => {
 return (
   <img src={n.img_src}/>
 )
})
```

this will diplay all the images.

Comment: I tried that as my first option but It didn't works. it render 404 error